# upload_to doesn't work when updating user profile?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

When my users create a profile, their image gets saved fine but when they update it it doesn't get saved. I also don't know how to pull the pic so that they can see it before updating it.

This is the form:

```
class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('city', 'profilepic')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(UpdateProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            profile.save()
        return profile
```

This is the view:

```
def updateprofile(request):



if request.method == 'POST':
    update_user_form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    update_profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

if update_user_form.is_valid() and update_profile_form.is_valid():
    update_user_form.save()

    '''************************************************'''
    profile = update_profile_form.save(commit=False)

    if 'profilepic' in request.FILES:
        profile.profilepic = request.FILES['profilepic']

    profile.save()

    '''************************************************'''


    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
else:
    update_user_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
    update_profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)


return render(request, 'updateprofile.html', {'update_user_form' : update_user_form, 'update_profile_form' : update_profile_form})
```

And this is model:

```
# this is model for user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)

    profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/Profile Pictures', blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    average_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ratings_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Uncomment if you don't want the slug to change every time the name changes
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you should pass `request.FILES` attribute too to the `Form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add request.FILES to the form:

```
update_profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                        instance=request.user)
```

By default django doesn't includes files in request.POST

Also, I think instance for `UserProfile` model should be `request.user.profile` instead of `request.user` or am I missing something here?

Follow instructions from [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: I updated my code per your advice and the django doc. but for some reason it still doesn't upload. I want to replace the old pic with the new one. Can you please advise further? thank you so much. I surrounded my edit with ****

Comment: There is no need to add the highlighted part. Just call `update_profile_form.save()` if form is valid. The form will save the files (if any). Also, the second `if` block should work better if it is indented inside the first `if` block.